# workflow_run in PR

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have some CI in my repo which has two separate workflows. Workflow B needs to run after workflow A completes. When I call workflow B from A:

```
name: HelmLint
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  push:
    branches:
      - main

...
...

  install:
    needs:
      - lint
    uses: ./.github/workflows/install.yaml
    secrets: inherit
```

Workflow B runs on the PR. Because it uses a matrix, I see this on the status checks:
[image]

However, these do not show up in the runs for this workflow under the actions tab: [image]
Which I need to have my CI badge in the readme in a 'passing' state.

If I instead do this for workflow B:

```
name: Install Helm Charts
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [HelmLint]
    types:
      - completed
```

Where 'HelmLint' is Workflow A, then this workflow B does not run on PR after workflow A. What do I need so that I can get my status badge in a passing state and the workflow running on PR?

Comment: You use the syntax to call a reusable workflow in your Workflow A (which would work with a `workflow_call` trigger). Using a `workflow_run` trigger, you don't need to add anything in the Workflow A, just wait for him to conclude auccessfully for the Workflow B to start.

Comment: @GuiFalourd as mentioned in the question, this isn't working

Comment: What happens when removing the `install` job from the Workflow A (HelmLint) ? Does the Workflow B (Install Helm Charts) runs successfully after the Workflow A is concluded ?